# MVC Form DataType email null value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, model-view-controller

I have a MVC Ajax form with text boxes data bound by a form model class.
In this class I have these fields:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name must be filled")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false,ErrorMessage = "Last Name must be filled")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Email must be filled")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

All three fields are bound with `@Html.EditorFor(p=>p.FirstName/LastName/Email)` - so this should be quite simple.

Everything works as it should, but when the form is posted the Email-field is always null.
I have tried to replace it with `<input type="email"` (...), and it´s also null.

So the conclusion is that when a form member has `type="email"`, the value is null.

Does anyone know why, and more important: How to solve it? (by the way, this is asp.mvc4)

edit: Here is my View:

```
<div id="result"></div>
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("FormTest", new AjaxOptions() {HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "result"}))
                {
                    {
                        Html.EnableClientValidation(true);
                    }
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)


                    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.EventForm.FirstName)
                    @Html.EditorFor(p => p.EventForm.FirstName)
                    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.EventForm.LastName)
                    @Html.EditorFor(p => p.EventForm.LastName)
                    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.EventForm.PhoneNumber)
                    @Html.EditorFor(p => p.EventForm.PhoneNumber)
                    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.EventForm.Email)
                    @Html.EditorFor(p => p.EventForm.Email)



                    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.EventForm.CompanyName)
                    @Html.EditorFor(p => p.EventForm.CompanyName)
                    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.EventForm.Adress)
                    @Html.EditorFor(p => p.EventForm.Adress)
                    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.EventForm.Zip)
                    @Html.EditorFor(p => p.EventForm.Zip)
                    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.EventForm.PostalCity)
                    @Html.EditorFor(p => p.EventForm.PostalCity)
                    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.EventForm.Country)
                    @Html.EditorFor(p => p.EventForm.Country)
                    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.EventForm.Comment)
                    @Html.EditorFor(p => p.EventForm.Comment)
                }
```

And my Controller action:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public PartialViewResult Index(EventViewModel form)
        {
            StoreEventRegistration(form.EventForm);

            return PartialView("PagePartial/FormSubmit", form.EventForm);
        }
```

As you probably understand, I haven´t added my whole Model, but the rest of the fields are created the same way as those referred to over.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Have you tried in your post method to take a `FormCollection` and get the value from there?

Comment: No, @Esteban , I will try that!

Comment: @Esteban : I tried with Post method taking a formCollection, but still I have 3 keys: Form.FirstName, Form.LastName and X-Requested-With. The Form.Email is still missing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting up your form in your view like this:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm(...))
{

}
```

If so ensure you include the jquery unobtrusive ajax min file otherwise the form will be posted back to the controller when using certain browsers (I think I hit this exact problem last week with IE7/8 - adding this file fixed it).

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/<your-path>/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

UPDATE:

Make sure you have the following set at controller or web.config level:

```
ClientValidationEnbled=true
UnobstrusiveJavaScriptEnabled=true
```

And it is my understanding that in order for all the moving parts to work you must include all of thse js files:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/<your-path>/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/<your-path>/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/<your-path>/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I´ve read somewhere that jquery.unobtrusive-ajax is not needed for mvc 4?

Comment: And there is no problem with the ajax functionality in my application, only with the input fields with type="email".

Comment: Are you using @Html.ValidationMessageFor() after each field?

Comment: If you have your AJAX set up correctly the form should only ever be posted back to the controller if it passes validation on the client. If you are using your own js function to do the ajax then the unobtrusive validation could be being bypassed ? You need to post more examples of your code

Comment: I do have a problem with validation. It never kicks in. The form is passed to the controller every time, even with an empty form.

Do you think that could be why the email-field pass null-values?
And is Jquery.unobtrusive-ajax script needed for MVC4 Applications?

Comment: I have edited my question so you can see my view and controller as well. @wysinawyg

Comment: I tried with the js now, and `ClientValidationEnbled=true
UnobstrusiveJavaScriptEnabled=true`set in my web.config, but still no changes. My Email address is stil null and my form is not being validated.